# Is there a way to track an URL traffics if the page doesn't exist but was directed to a working page?

Tags: google-analytics

1. A user enters https://example.com/mypage on the browser
2. .httaccess redirects to https://example.com/myfinallandingpage

I would like to track the traffics of /mypage.
/mypage is not an actual page, but /myfinallandingpage is a working page.

Does anybody know a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Out of the box you can't measure server-side redirects such as 301 or 302** since the browser JavaScript, and thus Google Analytics won't be executed on the redirect source pages.

**However you can by doing a little customization**:

- **Insert a URL parameter on the redirect destination page** eg `https://example.org/destination-page?ref=https://example.org/source-page` and track whatever you want on that destination apge
- **Perform server-side tracking**: you could handle your [redirects at PHP level](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), allowing you to use a [GA server-side tracking library](https://github.com/theiconic/php-ga-measurement-protocol) with [GA Client ID retrieved via the cookies in HTTP headers](https://segment.com/docs/connections/destinations/catalog/google-analytics/#passing-cookies-from-universal-analytics)

Comment: If I redirect the new URL with a parameter attached, will my Google Analytics record the full URI? i.e /myfinallandingpage?redirect=mypage

Comment: Yes by default GA records full URLs